# installation of ubuntu's kernel of 64 bits in a virtual machine VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, vmware, virtual-machine

I need to install avirtual machine using VMware with Ubuntu 64-bit on a real machine of 32 bits, my question is, will be possible to do this successfully? .. maybe the question is silly,but I would like to know is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare (and also VirtualBox, on a side node) virtualizes 64bit inside a 32bit machine.

Also, try [this](http://download3.vmware.com/software/wkst/VMware-guest64check-5.5.0-18463.exe). It will check if your machine works for virtualizing 64 bit machines. This works on VMware. I tried it. You just have to have the virtualization extensions in your CPU (is also relevant for VirtualBox)

Answer (score 2):

No, you must have a 64-bit capable CPU.  VMware does not virtualize the CPU.

Comment: Although you do not need to be running a 64-bit OS, I believe.

Comment: That is correct.  As long as the processor is 64-bit capable, the host OS can be 32-bit.

Comment: but the processor is 32 bit .. can have a 64-bit kernel?